# Volley doesn't respond in suspense function

Tags: android-volley, kotlin-coroutines

I'm trying to use coroutines instead of callbacks, but for some reason, the continuation doesn't resolve the API and the app just freeze:

```kotlin
suspend fun getRandomFact(): String =
    suspendCancellableCoroutine { cont ->
        val request = StringRequest(
            BASE_URL,
            { cont.resume(it) },
            { cont.resumeWithException(it) }
        )
        queue.add(request)
    }
```

Where `queue` is an attribute: `private val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context)` and `BASE_URL = "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/ability/1/"`

But if I use a simple `Log.d`:

```kotlin
fun getRandomFact(): String {
    val request = StringRequest(
        BASE_URL,
        { Log.d("RandomFact", it) },
        { Log.e("RandomFact", it.message.toString()) }
    )
    queue.add(request)
    return "dummy"
}
```

I can see the result of the request: `D/RandomFact: {"effect_c ...`

`getRandomFact` is used in a model with the following form:

```kotlin
class LoginViewModel : ViewModel(private val someRepository: SomeRepository) {
    fun putData() {
        runBloking {
            launch {
                val result = someRepository.getRandomFact()
                
                // some logic ...
            }
        }
        
        // ...
    }
}
```

Am I using `suspendCancellableCoroutine` in the wrong way?

> Yes, I was, and I've solved the issue using [`viewModelScode`](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/easy-coroutines-in-android-viewmodelscope-25bffb605471)

Comment: Could you show the code of how you call `getRandomFact()` function in both cases?

Comment: I was using `runBlocking` in the `MainActivity`, that's why `getRandomFact` didn't work, but I have solved this using [`viewModelScope`](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/easy-coroutines-in-android-viewmodelscope-25bffb605471), btw [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uiPYcSSjNTI) also help me to understand.